# Get list of all types/classes from Mono Assembly.dll in C++

Tags: c++, mono

I am trying to get a list of all the types and/or classes of a Mono Assembly file, but I could not find out how to do that. My goal is to load an `assembly.dll` in C++ and read its types and classes so I can use `mono_class_get_fields` etc.

This is what I tried with a known class name in the .dll, but `class1` was `NULL`. What is going wrong here?

`ExampleClass` is exending `System.Object`, which is in `mscorlib.dll`. Is there some kind of linking I need to do to get a proper `MonoClass *` inside my C++ code?

This is what I tried, but `mono_class_from_name` returns `NULL`:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <mono/metadata/assembly.h>
#include <mono/metadata/mono-config.h>
#include <mono/metadata/appdomain.h>
#include <mono/jit/jit.h>

int main()
{
    mono_set_dirs("C:\\Program Files\\Mono\\lib", "C:\\Program Files\\Mono\\etc");

    MonoDomain *domain;

    domain = mono_jit_init("test");

    MonoAssembly *assembly = mono_domain_assembly_open(domain, "C:\\Users\\Ik\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\MonoExtractor\\x64\\Debug\\Assembly-CSharp.dll");
    MonoImage *image = mono_assembly_get_image(assembly);

    // testing to see if I can get a known class
    MonoClass *class1 = mono_class_from_name(image, "", "ExampleClass");

    if (!class1) {
        printf("Could not find class!\n");
    }

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to put the other related dlls in the same directory too in order for it too work.